# Can I upgrade a Hercules Dirtrider 26" with gears and a disk brake?

Tags: gears, derailleur-rear, dropouts

I found that dropouts are needed for derailleur setup & fork space>120mm...can I install any hanger or weld a dropout to the frame?...and also the fork end gap was around 105mm in wheel fitted condition.Can I equip 5 or 6 speed gear set in my mtb? if yes can I also mount disc brake?[image: rear fork end of dirtrider]

[image: rear hub][image: rear fork end][image: dirtrider 26" frame]

Comment: The derailleur setup would probably cost more than your current bike... I advice to at least consider to sell this bike a buy another one, more suitable to your need.

Comment: Hercules is an Indian BSO brand.  Its not worth spending a lot of money on a BSO bike.   The frame does not have a caliper mount point and trying to add one is pain.  Your wheel's hub is not disk ready so won't hold a rotor.   Honestly, it would be cheaper to buy a better bike and use this one for shopping.

Comment: The moment you say "weld" you're getting into some pretty complicated and expensive territory.

Answer (score 4):

The derailer is sort of the easy part. Your frame could take a claw style derailer like this:

[image: Xundah]

Or you get one of these and have a lot more options:

[image: Sunrace]

120mm is the minimum rear spacing for derailer multi-speed rear hubs, so you would probably need to spread (bend) the frame.

You'll also need a new rear wheel, chain, and freewheel. Your cranks will probably not give workable chainline with a multispeed freewheel as they are now, which usually means toying with the BB spindle length, which is a pain on cottered cranks, and would probably also have you either removing the chain guard or finding a way of spacing it out.